# Not able to load python custom module from another directory

Tags: python-3.x

I want to load a custom python module from another directory. This question also has been asked many times and I have followed lot of links, and I have a solution. However, it is not working for me. I am fairly new to Python and looks like I am making a simple mistake which I am not able to find.

Below is the hierarchy. I want to import 'extollo_keyvault.py' inside 'testCode.py'. I can see the path for 'extollo_keyvault.py' when I print 'sys.path', however, the script execution fails saying that unable to find that module

[image: extollo-instance | |-hardened | | | |- extollo_keyvault.py | |- Instance | | | |-testCode.py | | |]

Code:

```
import os
import sys
path_to_extolloKeyvault_module = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'extollo_instance', 'hardened', 'extollo_keyvault.py')

sys.path.insert(0, path_to_extolloKeyvault_module)
import extollo_keyvault
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/manjug/source/repos/extollo-instance-march-31/extollo_instance/Instance/testCode.py", line 6, in <module>
    import extollo_keyvault
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extollo_keyvault'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code includes `/Instance`.

Try this code:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(os.getcwd())
path_to_extolloKeyvault_module = os.path.join(path.parent.absolute(), 'extollo-instance-march-31', 'extollo_instance', 'hardened'

sys.path.insert(0, path_to_extolloKeyvault_module)
import extollo_keyvault
```

Comment: still same issue: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/manjug/source/repos/extollo-instance-march-31/extollo_instance/Instance/testCode.py", line 9, in <module>
    import extollo_keyvault
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extollo_keyvault'

Comment: @ManjunathRao remove the py file from sys.insert, answer edited

Comment: same error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/manjug/source/repos/extollo-instance-march-31/extollo_instance/Instance/testCode.py", line 9, in <module>
    import extollo_keyvault
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extollo_keyvault'

Comment: could you print path_to_extolloKeyvault_module and put the output here as a comment

Comment: path_to_extolloKeyvault_module => C:\Users\manjug\source\repos\extollo_instance\hardened

Comment: I am sorry, it is same issue: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/manjug/source/repos/extollo-instance-march-31/extollo_instance/Instance/testCode.py", line 9, in <module>
    import extollo_keyvault
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extollo_keyvault'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230604/discussion-between-ketzoomer-and-manjunath-rao).